# LM20_PWLEN returns the minimum password lenght or the maximum password length?

Tags: windows, security, passwords

As per the following MSDN documentation LM20_PWLEN is maximum password length which is 14 characters. If this is the case then why does windows allow us to use more than 14 characters. I think this should be minimum password length.
im Confused. What does LM20_PWLEN specify?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370254(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`LM20_PWLEN` specifies the maximum password length that was allowed in certain older operating systems, such as DOS and Windows 3.11.

In all current versions of Windows, the maximum password length is `PWLEN`.

In some circumstances, passwords must be no more than `LM20_PWLEN` characters long, due to backwards compatibility restraints.  The default password for a new computer account is one such case.

There is no fixed minimum password length, although a minimum password length may be assigned by the system administrator.